# Upper Bound for Exponential Expression.

Tags: analysis, inequality, taylor-expansion, approximation

Let $a>0$.I would like to find an upper bound for the absolute value of the quantity
\begin{equation}
E(x,a) = \frac{ 2 (1-x)^a -\left(-x^2-x+1\right)^a-\left(x^2-x+1\right)^a}{\sqrt{(1-x)^{a} (1-(1-x)^a)}}
\end{equation}
when $x>0$ is close to $0$.

The series expansion in Mathematica gives
\begin{equation}
\left(\sqrt{a}-a^{3/2}\right) x^{7/2}+O\left(x^{9/2}\right)
\end{equation}

Is there a way to show that $|E(x,a)| \leq C x^2$, where $C>0$ is a constant for all $a \in (0,+\infty)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum of $a^{1/2}-a^{3/2}$ is $\frac 2{3\sqrt3} \approx 0.385$.  As long as $x \lt 1$ we can take $C$ to be this value because $x^{7/2} \lt x^2$ if $x \lt 1$.  You didn't specify how close $x$ is to zero, so we can take it small enough that the later terms in the expansion don't matter.

Comment: a could be greater than 1 and the difference could go over minus infinity

Comment: OP asked for any positive $a$, so we should take the maximum over positive $a$.

Comment: $\lim_{a\to \infty}a^{1/2}-a^{3/2} \to \infty$, $C=C(a)$.

Comment: @hyprfrco:  no, it is $-\infty$.  OP asked for a $C$ independent of $a$, so we have to give one that works for any $a$ in the range.  That is why I took the maximum.

Comment: Well, i would expect an absolute bound, but, an upper bound is requested.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You are right.  I lost some parentheses when putting it into Alpha which maximized $\sqrt a -(a^3)/2$ for me.  It wasn't strictly what I asked as I also had a^1/2 which should be $a/2$.  Thanks.  Fixed.

Comment: @RossMillikan in fact I just realized that I need an absolute bound. Sorry, I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Take the square of your function. You can get rid of that pesky square root and take L'hopital rule, and show easily that the limit exist for any fixed $a$...